# Selecting the form of the focused field when all forms have same name and id

Tags: javascript, jquery

A webpage has multiple forms with the same ID (id = abc); I want to do something when a visitor focuses on one of these forms. I've tried to do a focus on the first field of the form, like below but since the ID and names of the fields have the same name and id, it only works if the FIRST form's field is focused. How do I get jquery or javascript to know which form the user is on? 
I can do 
    jQuery( "#field1" ).focus(function() {
    alert( "test" );
    });
but again it will only work if I focus on the first form. I want to be able to do this on whichever form they focus upon.

Comment: > A webpage has multiple forms with the same ID (id = abc); First off, you shouldn't have more than one element with the same ID.

Answer (score 1):

***Please note you cannot have multiple items in an HTML document with the same ID, hence the name ID!***

In order to capture the form of any focused input, you can use something like the following:

```
var form = $(':focus').parent("form");
```

You can then attach events to the `form` variable and it will represent the currently focused form.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the element currently focused and find its parent form:

```
var $focusedform = $(':focus').parent("form");
```

$focusedform will refer to the form that currently has an element in focus